# My Spring based Restful webservice gives 404 when deploy to standalone tomcat instead of Eclipse's Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am using Spring, Jpa Hibernate to create a Restful Webservices. It worked fine with Eclipse's Setup of tomcat server. But when I tried to deploy its war file to standalone tomcat's webapp folder and restart the server, it gives 404 error.

What could be the cause? Am I missing some steps while deploying to standalone tomcat?

Edit:

Turns out when packaging the war through `mvn clean install`, its not packaging my web.xml and springcontext.xml. When I manually copy these file to the deployed war, the project work fine.

Now the question is, do any have idea why its not packaging those file.

Comment: I am using mvn clean install for WAR packaging and copying the war from /target folder. I am pretty sure URL is not incorrect. What else you meant by WAR packaging.

Comment: What are the page url's for both the working Eclipse and the non-working Tomcat?

Comment: I mean if you open the WAR, does it appear to be correct?  All your .class files under /WEB-INF/classes, all JARs under /WEB-INF/lib, all resources at the context root?

Comment: @duffymo yes it appears correct. As you said, all are in place.

Comment: @MikeSummers for testing purpose I kept an api in context root. So it localhost:8080/myproject/

Comment: Check logs/catalina.out and post its latest(bottom) contents in your main post.

Answer (score 1):

By default Eclipse projects put web stuff in a folder called `WebContent`. This is not where `maven` expects it, so you should convert your `Eclipse` project to a `maven` project by using Right Click on `Project->Configure->Convert to Maven` project. This will build a pom.xml that references the `WebContent` directory:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I'd start with the debugging:

- Can you connect to the standalone Tomcat at http://localhost:8080 ?

  - If not then you probably have a port problem
- Is the war expanded under $catalina_home/webapps ?

  - If not then you have a deploy problem
  - If you're not letting Tomcat's Manager auto-deploy then unzip
    the war in-place

We do exactly what you're up to on a daily basis. We develop in Eclipse, let Tomcat auto-deploy in Dev & QA, in Prod we deploy by hand as the Manager is disabled. Once you can get things to work in Eclipse (usually the problem) then typically it's a Tomcat config problem.